# Cannot apply condition for looping through datarow

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ado.net, datarow

I have apply looping in datarow and i need to check that if user role is admin, i need to apply some condition.

Now a user can have multiple roles say User Smith has 3 roles: Admin, Developer and Tester. Hence for smith the condition comes true. For Jane she has 4 roles: Developer, Tester, Analyst & Normal user, so for jane the condition become false (as she is not admin)

Now i have written code as

```
// filling up the dataTable.
DataTable dtAssignedRoles = (DataTable (Session[GlobalConstants.SESSION_USER_ASSGN_ROLE_DT]);
if (dtAssignedRoles != null && dtAssignedRoles.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtAssignedRoles.Rows)
    {
        if (dr["OT_ROLE"].ToString().ToUpper().Equals("ADMIN"))
        {
            // apply condition for admin here!
        }
    }
}

// Condition that would execute for Jane
if (strICol.Equals("N"))
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = string.Empty;
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Clear();
    Image imgIColumnDesc = new Image();
    imgIColumnDesc.ImageUrl = "~/Images/blackcircle.png";
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(imgIColumnDesc);
}
```

Problem: For smith the condition fails as although he is admin, he is also developer and tester. hence 2 conditions get applied; one for admin and another for non-admin (dev + tester)

Hence i guess, i need to check in all the rows and if there is one role with admin, the condition should be met. But i don't know how to do it?

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: So for user with both Admin and Tester roles two conditions should be applied or only Admin-specific?

Comment: Only admin specific. If user is admin, no other condition should get applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this helper function to determine if a user has a particular role...

```
    public bool hasRole(string role, DataTable dtAssignedRoles)
    {
        if (dtAssignedRoles != null && dtAssignedRoles.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtAssignedRoles.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["OT_ROLE"].ToString().ToUpper().Equals(role))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

EDIT: OR with Linq

```
    public bool hasRole(string role, DataTable dtAssignedRoles)
    {
     return dtAssignedRoles.AsEnumerable().Any(a => a["OT_ROLE"].ToString().ToUpper().Equals(role.ToUpper()));
    }
```

Then to use...

```
        if(hasRole("ADMIN",dtAssignedRoles))
        {
            //DO stuff
        }
        else if (hasRole("TESTER", dtAssignedRoles))
        {
            //Do Other Stuff
        }
```

Comment: @Xor power, sorry i'm not following your comment.

Comment: guess, you have understood the requirement

Answer (score 1):

If, after you apply the condition for the admin, you add the statement `break;`, this will break out of the loop and move onto the next step in the process.